# Detect the top of a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

**How can I detect the TOP of a ScrollView?** I have implemented code to detect the bottom, but I cannot seem to figure out the calculation that determines when the top has been reached.

```
     @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        int startPosition = t;
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));

        if (diff == startPosition){
            oListener.onTopReached();
        } else {
            nListener.BottomNotReached();
        }

/*        if (diff == 0 && mListener != null) {
            mListener.onBottomReached();
        } else if (diff == getTop()) {
            oListener.onTopReached();
        } else {
            nListener.BottomNotReached();
        }*/

        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Marteinn suggests](http://marteinn.se/blog/android-determinate-when-scrollview-has-reached-the-bottom/):

```
 @Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) { 

     if(view.getTop()==t){
        // reaches the top end
        }

    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1); 
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff 
     if( diff <= 0 ){ 
        // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
         Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
             }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt); 
}
```

Comment: ..and if I wanted to get the top?

Comment: @Coova then you check if (diff > 0)